# Matching css selectors with RegExp doesn't work in browser

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to match css selectors as can be seen here: 
https://regex101.com/r/kI3rW9/1
. It matches the teststring as desired, however when loading a .js  file to test it in the browser it fails both in firefox and chrome.

---

The .js file:

```
window.onload = function() {
    main();
}
main = function() {
    var regexSel = new RegExp('([\.|#][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.:_-]*) ?','g');
    var text = "#left_nav .buildings #rfgerf .rtrgrgwr .rtwett.ww-w .tw:ffwwwe";
    console.log(regexSel.exec(text));
}
```

In the browser it returns:`["#left_nav ", "#left_nav", index: 0, input: "#left_nav .buildings #rfgerf .rtrgrgwr .rtwett.ww-w .tw:ffwwwe"]`

So it appears it only captures the first selector with and without the whitespace, despite the whitespace beeing outside the () and the global flag set.

**Edit:**
So either looping over RegExp.exec(text) or just using String.match(str) will lead to the correct solution. Thanks to Wiktor's answer i was able to implement a convenient way of calling this functionality:

```js
function Selector(str){
 this.str = str;
}
with(Selector.prototype = new String()){
 toString = valueOf = function () {
  return this.str;
 };
}

Selector.prototype.constructor = Selector;
Selector.prototype.parse = function() {
 return this.match(/([\.|#][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.:_-]*) ?/g);
}
//Using it the following way:
var text = new Selector("#left_nav .buildings #rfgerf .rtrgrgwr .rtwett.ww-w .tw:ffwwwe");
console.log(text.parse());
```

I decided however using 
`/([\.|#][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.:_-]*) ?/g` over the suggested

`/([.#][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.:_-]*)(?!\S)/g` because it matches with 44 vs. 60 steps on regex101.com on my teststring.

Comment: You should use a regex literal.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the Global flag.  If you want multiple matches, you'll need a loop.

Comment: Maybe just use `(?!\S)`? `/([.#][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.:_-]*)(?!\S)/g`

Comment: You just need to run the `exec` in a loop. Or use `str.match(/[.#][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.:_-]*(?!\S)/g)` ([regex](https://regex101.com/r/fN2nN4/1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran `exec` once, so you got one match object. You'd need to run it inside a loop.

```js
var regexSel = new RegExp('([\.|#][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.:_-]*) ?','g');
var text = "#left_nav .buildings #rfgerf .rtrgrgwr .rtwett.ww-w .tw:ffwwwe";
while((m=regexSel.exec(text)) !== null) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

A regex with a `(?!\S)` lookaround at the end (that fails the match if there is no non-whitespace after your main consuming pattern) will allow simpler code:

```js
var text = "#left_nav .buildings #rfgerf .rtrgrgwr .rtwett.ww-w .tw:ffwwwe";
console.log(text.match(/[.#][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.:_-]*(?!\S)/g));
```

Note that you should consider using regex literal notation when defining your *static* regexps. Only prefer constructor notation with `RegExp` when your patterns are *dynamic*, have some variables or too many `/` that you do not want to escape.

Look also at `[.#]`: the dot does not have to be escaped and `|` inside is treated as a literal pipe symbol (not alternation operator).